# Assigned Generator Class on Hibernate Annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Hibernate newbie here.  I am working on a simple Hibernate mapping file.
When I am using the xml approach, I set the generator class to assigned.
There are certain logic that must be checked before an employee id is assigned so I cant generate it
automatically.

```
<id name="id" type="string" column="emp_id">
        <generator class="assigned">
        </generator>
</id>
```

But I am also studying the annotation type and annotation seems to be in thing nowadays as frameworks are moving away from
configuration files.  But I cant find any generation type to match the assigned value

```
public class Employee{
 String id; 
 @column(name="emp_id", unique=true)
 public String getID(){
  return id;
 }
}
```

Does this mean that I dont need to add any sequence generator annotation when it is assigned?  Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use the `@Id` annotation which lets you define which property is the identifier of your entity. You don't need to use the `@GeneratedValue` annotation because I don't think you want hibernate to generate this property for you.

```
@Id
String id;
```