# How to get grails to assign Id to a legacy Java object

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a java annotized domain object that I want to use in grails, this works fine, however all the generated templates use `Id` as the primary key. I tried to create a `XxxConstraints.groovy` file in the same package as my domain object, and added

```
mapping = { 
    id type:'assigned', name:<name of java field>, type: string 
}
```

but that does not seem to work.

The error I get when trying to render the gsp is `"class XYZ does not contain field id"`

By the way I am using grails 2.1.0.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What GSP are you talking about and how does the failing GSP code look?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about scaffolding views, they just have `id` field hardcoded, like: `<g:hiddenField name="id" value="\${${propertyName}?.id}" />` (sample from edit.gsp).

Just modify your GSPs by hand to use your key field.

If it's more than one class and you don't want to generate all the views, you can install the templates into your project sources with [`grails install-templates`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html) and modify those to use your PK field. Maybe Groovy wrappers for Java classes will have [ident()](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/ident.html) method, though not sure.

After looking at [the doc](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html), I'm in doubt if `mapping{}` DSL will work at all. Looks like only `constraints` section will work, and I believe [you only need `@Id` annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602808/assigned-generator-class-on-hibernate-annotations).